# Стоит ли разбивать решение задачи на классы?

Tags: c#, ооп, стандарт

Я пишу лабораторные роботы в университет по дисциплине, которая совмещает в себе программирование и математику. Пишу в стиле ООП, и не понимаю, как корректнее, с точки зрения стандартов программирования, стоит реализовать задачу.

Допустим, есть определённый интеграл, и нужно найти площадь под графиком, зная левую и правую границу и количество разбиений. У меня есть четыре способа решения этой задачи: метод левых прямоугольников, метод правых прямоугольников, метод трапеции и метод парабол. У меня есть два варианта как это всё реализовать в коде.

**Первый вариант** - создать один класс `Integral` с методом `Calculate`, у которого, по мимо выше перечисленных параметров, ещё будет указываться способ интегрирования (это удобно реализовать через перечисления).

**Второй варинт** - создать интерфейс IIntegral с методом `Calculate` и  реализовать его классом `Integral` с виртуальным методом `Calculate`, от последнего унаследовать четыре класса которые будут перегружать метод в зависимости от способа интегрирования.

С одной стороны удобней писать всё в одном классе, но меня терзает, что это как-то не в стиле ООП и, что следует неким образом применить наследование и полиморфизм.

Есть ли какой-то стандарт или правило как это правильно реализовывать?

Comment: я бы взял второй вариант и либо интерфейс выкинул из него, либо базовый класс. Иметь оба сразу вроде смысла не имеет. Для того, как делать "правильно" надо читать всякие SOLID / паттерны и прочие ООП штучки и много практиковаться, так как, как правило, теорию надо закреплять практикой.

Comment: По поводу дизайна классов - есть как минимум 2 ресурса почитать, книга "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина и "Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries" от Кржиштофа Квалины, одного из авторов дотнета, по которой есть даже раздел на MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/

Comment: А почему никто не предложил третий вариант - просто написать 4 функции. И все. Никаких ООП, перегрузок и подобного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача состоит из реализации 4-х различных методов подсчёта интеграла. Интеграл, в свою очередь, - это просто символ, которым обозначается функция интегрирования, это нельзя назвать объектом, как я считаю.

Основываясь на вышесказанном, я бы реализовал это в виде статического класса:

```
public static class Integral
{
    public static int Calculate1(...) => ...; // 1й метод
    public static int Calculate2(...) => ...; // 2й метод
    public static int Calculate3(...) => ...; // 3й метод
    public static int Calculate4(...) => ...; // 4й метод
}
```

**Почему здесь излишни интерфейсы?**

Интерфейс - это контракт. Интерфейсы нужны тогда, когда вы хотите гарантировать, что разные объекты или типы будут иметь некоторый общий функционал (методы и свойства), которым можно будет воспользоваться не зная о его реализации.

Так как интеграл это не объект, он не предпалагает другие классы, расширяющие его функционал. Следовательно и интерфейс было бы создавать излишне.

**Вы можете сказать, что интерфейс был бы не излишним, так как каждый метод интегрирования был бы реализован отдельным классом.**

Почему я считаю, что так не стоит делать, так это потому, что все классы, реализовывающие интерфейс, будут содержать по одной функции. Не рационально создавать отдельный класс ради одного, да к тому же статического, метода.

**P.S.**

К слову о вашем втором варианте решения задачи. Если уж и создавать интерфейс `IIntegral`, то стоит от него напрямую реализовывать 4 класса с реализацией метода `Calculate`. Прослойка в виде некоторого класса `Integral` с виртуальным методом `Calculate` будет излишеством в квадрате.

Comment: @aepot прошу поправить меня, если где-то я оказался не прав

Comment: решение в статических методах не выдерживает никакой критики.
1. задачи по вычислению могут быть достаточно сложными, поэтому лучше каждый метод реализовывать в своем классе, а не в общей партянке, да еще и в статических методах, которые невозможно сделать повторно используемыми (например, если какие-то вычисления будут одинаковые в нескольких способах)
2. Модифицирование одного общего класса - всегда менее надежно, чем модификация одного класса, отвечающего за свой способ расчета.

Comment: Я бы сделал реализацию по второму варианту.
Интерфейс можно создавать если эта структура классов будет публиковаться в какую-то библиотеку. Для локального проекта интерфейс как таковой можно не использовать

Comment: `"задачи по вычислению могут быть достаточно сложными..."` - вычисления интеграла методами, нужными автору, не являются сложными и каждый метод уместиться в 20 строк кода

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант я бы сразу отбросил, т.к. плодить классы, просто потому-что у них разные способы вычисления - не круто. Тут усматриваю нарушение принципа единственной ответственности: 1 задача - 1 класс и наоборот 1 класс - 1 задача. Вся логика интегрирования должна быть инкапсулирована в одном классе.

---

Первый вариант следует реализовать так:

1. Создать класс Integral
2. Для каждого из 4х способов вычисления реализовать отдельный
   **закрытый**(private) метод с параметрами
3. Создать **открытый** метод Calculate, принимающий Enum(метод
   вычисления) и аргументы. В нём, в зависимости от значения Enum, вызывать конкретные методы, передавая в них аргументы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135496/discussion-between---and-kovadim).